# Is it legally required to show US-Customers the tax inclusive amount at checkout?

Tags: sales-tax, auction

I am developing an auction site also for use in the US Market. Obviously the seller needs to pay the appropriate taxes but I wonder if I can show the customers' prices with tax included.

Comment: As an American, I’ve never seen prices quoted including tax.  So your users will expect taxes to be added to whatever price you present unless your UI manages to overcome that very strong expectation.  That’s probably not where you want to invest your UI resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably varies on a state by state basis. I know that in Massachusetts the price must be pre-tax with tax added at time of transaction.

Taxes may also vary depending on the nature of what is being sold.

Also, when planning this, be aware that some states have yearly "tax holidays" on which sales of some (not necessarily all) categories will not be taxed.  That's often restricted to in-state sales.

Basically, don't assume it is simple, or that it won't change

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the ability to list your prices as tax inc;luded varies by state, but also the nature of the business.

For example [Maryland](https://marylandtaxes.gov/business/sales-use/special-situations/tax-included-sales.php):

> Tax Included Sales
>
> Effective January 3, 2008, a vendor may assume and absorb all or any
> part of the sales and use tax on a retail sale and pay that tax on
> behalf of the buyer.
>
> The vendor must, however, continue to separately state the tax from
> the sales price at the time of sale to the purchaser. If the vendor
> absorbs all or any part of the tax on the sale, the vendor shall pay
> the tax with the return that covers the period in which the vendor
> makes the sale.

and this non confusing statement from [Iowa](https://tax.iowa.gov/iowa-sales-and-use-tax-guide):

> The retailer must add the tax to the price and collect the tax from
> the purchaser. The retailer cannot indicate that the sales tax is
> being “absorbed.”
>
> A retailer may include the tax in the price, but must post a notice or
> make a statement on the invoice that the purchase price includes the
> sales tax. This is typically done when selling alcoholic beverages or
> admissions to movie theaters or sporting events.

The issue you will have is that the tax rate can vary not just by state but within a state. In some cases the sales tax rate is set by the county or city. For example [Virginia](https://www.tax.virginia.gov/retail-sales-and-use-tax): It ranges from 5.3 percent to 7.0 percent. That would mean that your sales price for a product would vary based on where the item is being shipped instead of having one fixed price but vary the tax amount. The logic to split the money between taxes owed to the state and those that are owned to the county, and the rest assigned to the business would be just as complex. The receipt would most likely still have to show how much tax was being collected.

Comment: The safe answer, from a programmer's point of view, is to always show the price and tax separately; nobody will require that you combine them before adding up the bill, but some require that you don't. And yes, that means the bill for auctioned items will be very be in nice round numbers unless the bid was in very awkward numbers. I have no idea whether giving the customer the ability to enter a total and breaking it up for them into price and tax before entering the bid would be permitted, but I would expect anyone who did that to be outbid by someone who didn't.